# как сделать псевдоэлемент :before видимым, а основной элемент скрыть?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать вместо стандартного поля для загрузки файла просто квадратик. Для этого использую псевдоэлемент :before. Но при установке свойства display:none основного элемента этот псевдоэлемент тоже пропадает. Как исправить?

```
<input type="file" class="photo">
```

css

```
.photo{
display:none;
}
.photo:before{
content:'';
width:128px;
height:110px;
border:1px dashed var(--divider-color);
border-radius: 3px;
margin:20px 40px 0 0;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вопрос в заголовке отличен от вашего примера кода. Вам с любым примером подойдёт вариант или именно с `input type="file"`? Дело в том, что стилизованный `input type="file"` вообще не реализуется так, как вы это предлагаете сделать, это сложнее: после добавления файла, его название где-то должно отображаться. Также зачастую добавляют кнопку удаления файла(крестик). Вот пример: стилизованная кнопка для загрузки файла: http://bit.ly/2rYrNoV а так выглядит после добавления файла: http://bit.ly/2rZVBSa

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно сделать без псевдоэлементов (когда-то таким способом пользовался):

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

.photo {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="photo">
  <input type="file">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать:

```
visibility:hidden
```

вместо:

```
display:none
```

и в псевдоэлементах ставить `visibility: visible`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" class="photo" id="photo">
<label for="photo"><\label>
```

```
#photo {
    display: none;
}

label {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```